# Memory leak without allocating any memory?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm working on a coding assignment for a C++ class. When I run my program I seem to be dealing with a memory leakage issue, which is weird since I am NOT explicitly allocating any memory in my code. I ran the program under gdb, and it seems as though the program crashes when running the destructor for a Deck object. I tried stepping through the code, but I when I do so I end up in a host of .h files related to vectors. Then suddenly, it stops. I tried going to a TA for some help, but they seem to be as perplexed as I am on the issue.

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
# include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

//function signatures
float bustProbability (const int);


class Deck
{
public:
    //data members
    vector <int> cardArray;
    vector <int> wasteCards;

    //constructor
    Deck();

    //methods
    void shuffleDeck();
    void populateDeckWithCards();
    void removeCopyCards();

    int dealCard();
    int remainingCards();
    void showCards();
};

void Deck::removeCopyCards() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < wasteCards.size(); i++) {
        bool removedCopy = false;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cardArray.size() && removedCopy == false; j++) {
            if (cardArray[j] == wasteCards[i]) {
                cardArray.erase (cardArray.begin() + j - 1);
                removedCopy = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int Deck::dealCard() {
    if (remainingCards() > 0) {
        int tmp = cardArray.back();
        wasteCards.push_back(tmp);
        cardArray.pop_back();
        return tmp;
    }

    else {
        populateDeckWithCards();
        removeCopyCards();
        shuffleDeck();
        //shuffle method
        int tmp = cardArray.back();
        cardArray.pop_back();
        return tmp;
    }
}

void Deck::populateDeckWithCards() {
    //populate regular cards into array
    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cardArray.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    //populate J, Q, K into array
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cardArray.push_back(10);
        }
    }

    //populating array with Aces... treating them as special case '100'
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cardArray.push_back(100);
    }

    return;
}

void Deck::showCards() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cardArray.size(); i++) {
        cout << cardArray[i] << endl;
    }
}

Deck::Deck() {
    wasteCards.clear();
    cardArray.clear();
    populateDeckWithCards();
    shuffleDeck();
}

void Deck::shuffleDeck() {
    int n = cardArray.size();

    for(int a = n-1; a > 0; a--) {
        int min = 0;
        int max = a;
        int j = min + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (max-min + 1) + 1);

        int tmp = cardArray[a];
        cardArray[a] = cardArray[j];
        cardArray[j] = tmp;
    }

    return;
}

int Deck::remainingCards() {
    return cardArray.size();
}


class Player {
public:
    //data members
    vector <int> playerHand;

    //constructor
    Player();

    //methods
    bool isBust();
    int count();
    void hit(Deck&);
    void stand();
    bool muckHand();
    void showHand();
};

Player::Player() {
    playerHand.clear();
}


void Player::showHand() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < playerHand.size(); i++) {
        cout << playerHand[i] << endl;
    }

    return;
}


int Player::count() {
    int handCount = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < playerHand.size(); i++) {
        if (playerHand[i] != 100)
            handCount += playerHand[i];

        else {
            if (playerHand[i] == 100) {
                if ((handCount) > 11) {
                    handCount += 1;
                }

                else
                    handCount += 10;
            }
        }
    }

    return handCount;
}

bool Player::isBust() {
    if (count() > 21)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}

void Player::hit(Deck& d) {
    playerHand.push_back(d.dealCard());
}

void Player::stand() {
    return;
}

bool Player::muckHand() {
    playerHand.clear();
    return true;
}


float bustProbability (const int threshHold) {
    int threshHoldReached = 0;
    Deck myDeck;
    Player myPlayer;
    Player dealer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        myPlayer.hit(myDeck);
        dealer.hit(myDeck);
        myPlayer.hit(myDeck);
        dealer.hit(myDeck);

        while (myPlayer.count() < threshHold) {
            myPlayer.hit(myDeck);
        }

        if (!(myPlayer.isBust())) {
            ++threshHoldReached;
        }

        myDeck.wasteCards.clear();
        myPlayer.muckHand();
        dealer.muckHand();
    }

    float bustFraction = float(threshHoldReached)/float(10000);
    return bustFraction;
}

int main () {
    cout << "blackjack simulation" << endl;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    cout << bustProbability(19);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm incredibly sorry for just posting my code, but I've spend 4 days on this issue, and I can't even begin to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Try making a [mcve]. There's a lot of code that probably has nothing to do with the problem, and if you test each part of the code separately so that you can figure out which parts are irrelevant, you can narrow down the problem and potentially fix it yourself.

Comment: What makes you think you have memory leaks? Is your program using an abnormal amount of memory? If you run your program in a debugger it should have stopped at the point of the crash. Are you sure you're using the debugger right?

Comment: Your code may not explicitly allocate and deallocate memory, but the vectors do.  Both the `Deck` and `Player` types manage vectors. The onus is on you (the programmer) to ensure the vectors are used correctly. One problem is in `Deck::RemoveCopyCards()`, which calls `cardArray.erase (cardArray.begin() + j - 1);` in a loop over `j`. The catch is that `erase()` resizes the vector, which invalidates any variables being used as an index (like `j`).  By continuing to use `j` as an array index` without resetting, the loop has undefined behaviour. Losing track of memory is a possible symptom.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. Well, under the debugger, after the return statement, it takes me to the lines where the objects are declared. The program crashes on the line where I assume the default destructor would run... and the crash references memory addresses. ^^^Will definitely try and use a better code posting style in the future.

Comment: @Peter shouldn't cause UB as `cardArray.size()` is checked for each iteration, still probably doesn't do what it's supposed to though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least the line

```
cardArray.erase (cardArray.begin() + j - 1);
```

which seems to be dubious in case of `j = 0`

Comment: Valgrind gave output that indicated possible problem in `Deck::removeCopyCard`

Comment: Duh. I was going crazy. I even tried changing the implementation to using pointers and forcibly allocating memory. You're a lifesaver!